# Include java code to display text in latex

Tags: java

is it possible to do something like the following in texlipse?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}  
\begin{document}

\section{Title}
import java
\subsection{Subtitle}

I want to display some java result

\begin{lstlisting}   
 printMyString()       
\end{lstlisting}              
\end{document}
```

Where printMyString() is for example:

```
public String printMyString() {
return "Hello World";
}
```

thanks!

Comment: What should the output look like? Do you want the string `printMyString()` to be replaced by the entire procedure, or just `"Hello World"`? [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) does provide `\lstinputlistings` which can input from a file and you can specify a `linerange`. Alternatively, there's a `literate` replacement that you could use.

Comment: I want only Hello World to be displayed, thanks

Comment: @Franky: That would require a TeX engine with a build-in JVM; such a beast doesn't exist yet. The best you can do is have TeX execute other programs and use their output (`\write18`) or use LuaTeX and it's build-in Lua interpreter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although I'm not a fan of on-the-fly computation inside a document, here's a possible solution using [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/):

> BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable Java source interpreter with
>   object scripting language features, written in Java. BeanShell
>   dynamically executes standard Java syntax and extends it with common
>   scripting conveniences such as loose types, commands, and method
>   closures like those in Perl and JavaScript.

There we go.

```
paulo@alexandria Sandbox$ ls
bsh.jar        test.tex
```

My humble code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calljava}{\ttfamily\@@input|"java -cp bsh.jar bsh.Interpreter tmp.bsh"}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{java}
{\VerbatimOut{tmp.bsh}}
{\endVerbatimOut\calljava}

\begin{document}

My first code.

\vspace{2em}

\begin{java}
int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b) {
   return a + b;
}
System.out.println(addTwoNumbers(10, 20));
\end{java}

\vspace{2em}

My second code.

\vspace{2em}

\begin{java}
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   System.out.println("I like ducks!\\par");
}
\end{java}

\end{document}
```

Running with `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex`:

[image: I like ducks!]

The idea is quite simple: get the body of the `java` environment and add it to a temporary file named `tmp.bsh`, run the interpreter from `bsh.jar` passing the temporary file to be executed, and capture the output.

My good friend egreg mentioned that this code doesn't work with `xetex` or `luatex`, unless we write another auxiliary file and input it. Let's stick with `pdflatex` for a while then. `:)`

Hope it helps. `:)`